# Отчёт через FastReport в Excel - ошибка "Доступ к файлу невозможен"

Tags: delphi, excel, fastreport

Что я сделал не так?

`frxXLSExport`, выдаёт такое окно (скрин)

> Raised exception class EOleException with message 'Доступ к файлу невозможен. Проверьте следующее...'`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот код реализации экспорта (с `frxPDFExport` отлично работает):

```
    FrxReport1.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\out\tmp_file.tmp');
    
    frxXLSExport1.ShowDialog := false;
    frxXLSExport1.Background := true;
    
    frxReport1.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\out\tmp_file.tmp');
    frxReport1.PrepareReport();
    frxXLSExport1.FileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\out\выгрузка_в_ФРДО.xls';
    frxXLSExport1.OpenExcelAfterExport:= True;
    frxReport1.Export(frxXLSExport1);
```

Ведь теоретически всё верно. Аналогия по `frxPDFExport` - всё работает.

Но в чём загвоздка с Excel?

Comment: У вас не прикрепился скриншот. И лучше бы приводить текст ошибки еще и текстом.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, зарапортовался, пока писал мысль забыл про скрин. Прикрепил.

Comment: Тут только отладка может показать что не так. 1. Установите пожалуйста точки останова в соответствующих местах и проверьте все выше перечисленные пункты. 2. На какой строчке падает ошибка? 3. Нет ли уже запущенных экземпляров Excel которые не дают создать отчёте?

Comment: Ну, и на всякий случай - откуда запускаете приложение? Не с Рабочего ли Стола? (Про наличие папки `out` не спрашиваю, чтобы не обидеть). Если с Рабочего Стола, то не кириллицей ли имя пользователя задано? Не слишком ли длинный путь к папке `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` получился?